# This error keeps showing up on my desktop

Tags: popup

[This Javascript error keeps showing up on my desktop, and when i delete it another one will pop up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnOG9.png)

Can anybody with knowledge about this please help me?

Oh the image is on Danish so yeah. Translated it says that there was a script-error with the script, and asks if i still want to play the script on this site.

Comment: Do you have access to the url for require.js ? If you put this url on your browser what does it show ?

Comment: What is the translation of the error message?  Is this showing up when you're working on specific code?  What is that code?  When you debug that code, when does the error occur?  We don't know *anything* about your computer, you need to tell us what's happening.

Comment: Oh the image is on Danish so yeah. Translated it says that there was a script-error with the script, and asks if i still want to play the script on this site.

Comment: @FrederikWaltherLiberothChri What about my comment ?

Comment: so you will need to acces this link: https://ubp-common-us-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/require/require.js

Comment: If you use Internet Explorer, have a look here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308260/how-to-troubleshoot-script-errors-in-internet-explorer

Comment: I think it's because i deleted some files that were running the script, but i don't know which script i deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution Found**

1. Go to *Control Panel*
2. Go to *Programs and Functions*
3. See if there is any program that refers to the *url-error-message* you got, and if there is, delete it.

***Note*** If the program is a program that you need to have for running your system or just an important program, don't delete it, there could be other ways to fix it.

***Other ways to fix it***
 1. Start up the installer that you used to install the program, if there is a button that says "*Repair software/program*" or something like that; tap the button.

2. If there isn't a button that says "*Repair software/program*" (or something like that); try to install the program again.